# First MacOS Apple Script: it works, but not with lid closed

Tags: macos, applescript

I completed my first Apple Script using the script editor. The purpose is to speak text when some conditions are met. Works perfectly fine with lid open.

script is running on MacBook Pro Late 2013 w/ Catalina 10.15.7.
Script is also meant for: MacBook Air M1 Late 2020 w/ Big Sur 11.3 (not implemented yet)

Issue:
Script doesn't speak text while lid is closed. Is there any way to make it continue to run (and speak text) while the lid is closed?

Here is the script (short version) though it is not relevant to the question:

```
set Cap to (do shell script "ioreg -w0 -l | grep ExternalChargeCapable")

tell Cap to set {wallPower} to {last word of paragraph 1}
if wallPower = "Yes" then
    return 0
else
    set Pct to (do shell script "pmset -g batt | grep -Eo \"\\d+%\" | cut -d% -f1")
    if Pct ≤ 10 then
        display notification "Batterij 10%. Meteen opladen." with title "Batterij bijna leeg!" sound name "Sosumi"
        ##      delay 300
        ## say "Batterij 10%. Meteen opladen."
    end if
end if
```

Thanks! Pete

Comment: How is this script implemented?

Comment: Script was copied to /etc folder. Then I created a plist that calls the script. See this web site for the source: https://jmmoloney.com/blog/2019/02/06/batteryscript

Comment: First of all I wouldn't use this particular method, both the **AppleScript** _script_ as coded and using `launchd`. If I needed such a task, I'd consider looking at the **Trigger when battery reaches** in [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk), or use [**Hammerspoon**](https://www.hammerspoon.org) and its **API**'s **hs.battery** and **hs.battery.watcher** to trigger something, using e.g. **hs.osascript.applescript** or **hs.osascript.applescriptFromFile**. As the latter option is free, I'd go for it since I already use **Hammerspoon**. However, certainly I'd try both.

Comment: That said, otherwise, I think you would have to implement a method to keep your system from sleeping using the method you currently are.

Comment: Thanks @user3439894, I'll look into that. This is my first script so I'm probably the least experienced around here. Actually I found out it's worse than I thought as the script won't run even when the screen dims due to power saving. Creating the full script took me a day's work and in fact it's doing exactly what I wanted, just not all the time.

Comment: @user3439894 the big question is, whether Power Manager or Hammerspoon can actually perform what I have now during blank screen / screen saver and lid closed.

Comment: My guess is they would work better then the method you are presently using. I'm just not in a position at the present time to check it out myself.  I personally never use a screen saver and if I did, I definitely would not use it while on battery power.

Comment: @Peter376 will the MacBook, with the lid closed, have an external monitor attached?